# Contextmenu modal interaction collector error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot like this that I wrote to give this warning, but after a while the bot goes offline and gives this error. I tried different ways to solve it, but even though I tried, I couldn't get any results. How can we solve this?

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isUserContextMenuCommand()) {
     if (interaction.commandName === 'Warn / Uyarı') {
      const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('warnUserModal')
        .setTitle('Yetkili Uyarı Formu')
        .setComponents(
        new ActionRowBuilder().setComponents(
            new TextInputBuilder()
              .setLabel('Oyun içi nickname')
              .setCustomId('userid')
              .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
              .setRequired(true)
              .setMaxLength(32)
          )
        );
      await interaction.showModal(modal);
      const modalSubmitInteraction = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
        filter: (i) => {
          console.log('Await modal submit');
          console.log(i.fields);
          return true;
        },
        time: 120000,
      }).catch(error => {
        // Catch any Errors that are thrown (e.g. if the awaitModalSubmit times out after 60000 ms)
        console.error(error)
        return null
      })
      const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(0x0099FF)
      .setAuthor({ name: 'Uyarı Alan VAR!', iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/569642268932309002/a_ebd47f6c9f159d5cd4d0a3ad2804afc2.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
      .setThumbnail('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3310/3310161.png')
      .addFields(
        { name: `Uyaran Yetkili`, value: `${interaction.user.globalName}\n\n` },
        { name: `Uyarılan`, value: `${interaction.targetMember} / ${interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('userid')}\n**Steam ID**\n*${modalSubmitInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('email')}*\n**Kaçıncı Uyarı?**\n*${modalSubmitInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('reason2')}*\n**Uyarı Nedeni**\n*${modalSubmitInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('reason')}*\n[Ceza kayıt/ss görmek için tıkla](${modalSubmitInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('reason3')})`, inline: true },
      )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'IMPARATOR GAMING', iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/569642268932309002/a_ebd47f6c9f159d5cd4d0a3ad2804afc2.png' });

      modalSubmitInteraction.reply({
        embeds: [exampleEmbed],
        ephemeral: false,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional in your code.

```js
const modalSubmitInteraction = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
  ...
}).catch(error => {
    // Catch any Errors that are thrown (e.g. if the awaitModalSubmit times out after 60000 ms)
    console.error(error)
    return null
})
```

When a user does not respond in time discord.js will throw an error, that should be handled as the user not responding rather than an actual error ocurring.